# HTML 1 input text for different forms/methods

Tags: html, jsp, forms, http-post

I am wanting to send POST/GET requests to one of my `.jsp`s. I thought about using 2 buttons but only 1 input text as the `action` for the 2 buttons is actually the same and only the `mehod` differs. Right now I only have 1 `<form>` with the input text as well as the button.

```
<form action="systemDetail.jsp" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="get" name="paramName" /> <input type="submit"
        value="Submit GET" />
</form>
```

Preferably I would now like to have a second button which uses `POST` method for the exact same call. I am fairly new to this subject all together.

My questions:

1. Is what I want even possible or should I use 2 input boxes as well as 2 buttons?
2. How can I realize it if its possible?

---

Please note that I do not want to use PHP, JavaScript or anything else. Only HTML and JSP/JSTL are okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this method for submitting in both methods

```
<form action="systemDetail.jsp" method="get">
   <input type="text" id="get" name="paramName" /> 
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" formmethod="post">Submit using POST</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This one works fine, but I get a notification `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Undefined attribute name 
  (formmethod).
 - Undefined attribute name 
  (formmethod).` on the `formmethod`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer are you using eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, its easier than just some text editor. I know that eclipse sometimes tells useless stuff, but not sure how relevant it is in this case